# How are you actually supposed to include JS inside a dynamically loaded partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know there are several questions concerning this, but I still think that it's there are a few areas that could use some clarification since the Turbolinks way of doing it **(1 js file to rule them all)** apparently goes straight out the window when starting to include content that is dynamically loaded via Ajax.

So, regarding content that is dynamically loaded via Ajax inside `_partial.html.erb`'s and thus not initially recognised by the DOM and unable bind any JS to new elements that are loaded;

*I have a sneaky suspicion* that the "Rails way" of dynamically binding JavaScript events to **new** elements is to **put any JavaScript inside the `js.erb` file that dynamically renders the partial** (?) But it somehow feels unintuitive to split all the javascript into so many different small files. I am currently including most of my JS inline each `_partial.html.erb` file which is giving me a massive headache when it comes to binding and unbinding events (which also btw feels really messy not to mention unintuitive).

Also, are `js.erb` files that are NOT in the asset pipeline, minified in production? Or are you supposed to put each js.erb file inside the Asset Pipeline for it to be minified?

-- Or am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Comment: The JS way of binding events to future DOM elements is to use event bubbling, e.g., you bind on a higher-level DOM element and put a selector in.

Comment: You mean like  for example: $(".element").on("click", function(e) {   var target = $(e.target); if (target.is(element)) {doStuff();} }); ?

Comment: No (not even sure what that means). I mean like http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events